# Improve performance on Update with WHERE IN Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a sql statement that already exists (verifying the performance) and I found two update sentences very similar that are using WHERE IN (Subquery) clauses and I think they are very slow, I ask for your help to find another way that both sentences works and do the job more faster.

Here is the "mock" code

```
    UPDATE Table1 SET IdUser = @NewUserId
    WHERE IdTask IN
    (
    SELECT T.IdTask
    FROM Business N
    JOIN Process P ON N.IdBusiness = P.CodBusiness
    JOIN Proyect Pr ON P.CodProyect = Pr.IdProyect
    JOIN Etap E ON E.CodProyect = Pr.IdProyect
    JOIN Task T ON T.CodEtap = E.IdEtap
    WHERE IdBusiness = @IdBusiness AND
    T.Flag = 0
    )

    UPDATE Table2 SET Flag = 1
    WHERE CodTask IN
    (
    SELECT T.IdTask
    FROM Business N
    JOIN Process P ON N.IdBusiness = P.CodBusiness
    JOIN Proyect Pr ON P.CodProyect = Pr.IdProyect
    JOIN Etap E ON E.CodProyect = Pr.IdProyect
    JOIN Task T ON T.CodEtap = E.IdEtap
    JOIN TaskAdvan TA ON TA.CodTask = T.IdTask
    WHERE IdBusiness = @IdBusiness AND
    T.Flag = 0
    )
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Kill the subquery? Give us query plans?

Comment: Consider moving to Exists: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--UPDATE using Inner JOIN

    UPDATE  A
    SET     A.IdUser = @NewUserId
    FROM    Table1 AS A
            JOIN ( SELECT   T.IdTask
                   FROM     Business N
                            JOIN Process P
                            ON N.IdBusiness = P.CodBusiness
                            JOIN Proyect Pr
                            ON P.CodProyect = Pr.IdProyect
                            JOIN Etap E
                            ON E.CodProyect = Pr.IdProyect
                            JOIN Task T
                            ON T.CodEtap = E.IdEtap
                   WHERE    IdBusiness = @IdBusiness AND
                            T.Flag = 0
                 ) B
            ON A.IdTask = B.IdTask
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    UPDATE  A
    SET     A.Flag = 1
    FROM    Table2 AS A
            JOIN ( SELECT   T.IdTask
                   FROM     Business N
                            JOIN Process P
                            ON N.IdBusiness = P.CodBusiness
                            JOIN Proyect Pr
                            ON P.CodProyect = Pr.IdProyect
                            JOIN Etap E
                            ON E.CodProyect = Pr.IdProyect
                            JOIN Task T
                            ON T.CodEtap = E.IdEtap
                            JOIN TaskAdvan TA
                            ON TA.CodTask = T.IdTask
                   WHERE    IdBusiness = @IdBusiness AND
                            T.Flag = 0
                 ) AS B
            ON A.CodTask = B.IdTask
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think the subquery is expensive to process, you can store the intermediate results in a temp table or table variable. Then you can use that in subsequent updates.

```
DECLARE @filter TABLE(IdTask INT PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO @filter
SELECT T.IdTask
FROM Business N
JOIN Process P ON N.IdBusiness = P.CodBusiness
JOIN Proyect Pr ON P.CodProyect = Pr.IdProyect
JOIN Etap E ON E.CodProyect = Pr.IdProyect
JOIN Task T ON T.CodEtap = E.IdEtap
WHERE IdBusiness = @IdBusiness AND
T.Flag = 0

UPDATE t1 SET IdUser = @NewUserId
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN @filter f ON f.IdTask = t1.IdTask

UPDATE t2 SET Flag = 1
FROM Table2 t2 INNER JOIN @filter f ON f.IdTask = t2.CodTask
```